# Python: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I'm working on the capstone project for Udacity's Full Stack Web Developer. I consider myself a beginner developer so please be kind :D

I'm working on the backend for my project but I'm getting stuck with this error:

```html
(env) C:\Repos\FSND_Capstone_Project\backend>flask db init
Usage: flask db init [OPTIONS]
Error: While importing "api", an ImportError was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\repos\fsnd_capstone_project\backend\env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 236, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Repos\FSND_Capstone_Project\backend\api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .database.models import setup_db, Manager, Project, Category
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I also have the following folder structure that I'm trying to create:

[Folder structure][image: 1]

I don't see what the error might be. Any tip of advice will be very well received.

I also attached my Github's repo link:

https://github.com/jovillarroelb/FSND_Capstone_Project

Thanks in advance!

Regards!

Comment: I think you have to `from database.models import setup_db` ... because `.database.models` only works if backend is a package itself (has a `__init__.py`) file

Comment: However, I am really not sure about this, the same error was making me troubles also a few times, will follow this for further answers

Comment: Thanks @FlorianD. Indeed was what you mentioned! If it is not a package, there is no need for the "." :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to `from database.models import setup_db` because `.database.models` only works if backend is a package itself (has a `__init__.py` file)